# How to crop out a detected circle as a square?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, crop

I have detected a circle as shown below:

[image]

As later I want to detect what speed limit is in the detected sign, how do I crop it out so that I am left with an image like below?

[image]

When program finishes it, it shows me where the center is and the radii in terminal.

```
centers =

  248.4873  170.4811


radii =

   24.5024
```

I know how to use `imcrop` but how do I use the values that are returned instead of writing in them myself, as there might be more than 1 circle detected?

**Code:**

```
I = imread('p1.tif');
subplot(3,3,1); imshow(I); title('Original Image'); 
%sharpen edges
B = imsharpen(I);
subplot(3,3,2); imshow(B); title('sharpened edges');

%find circles
Img = im2bw(B(:,:,3));
minRad = 20;
maxRad = 90;
[centers, radii] = imfindcircles(Img, [minRad maxRad], ...
                                    'ObjectPolarity','bright','sensitivity',0.87)
imagesc(Img);
viscircles(centers, radii,'Color','green');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have one centre and one radius. This should do it

```
rect = [centers(1)-radii,centers(2)-radii,2*radii,2*radii]
I2 = imcrop(I,rect)
```

For multiple circles you can do this process for each of the circle returned in a loop.

Comment: Thank you. Works perfectly!

Comment: @Powisss You can also crop the circle interactively using `I2 = imcrop` for the required image.